# Delete rows of multiple parent and foreign keys in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys, cascading-deletes

I'm a beginner in SQLite. I have tried to delete the row from TableA and it should delete relevant connected table rows too.

```
TableA
id
name

TableB
id
tbidA ref key TableA(id)
name
tbidC ref key TableC(id)
tbidD ref key TableD(id)
tbidE ref key TableE(id)

TableD
id
name

TableE
id
name

TableF
id
name

TableG
id
tbidE ref key TableE(id)
name
```

I tried `JOINS` but it throws a syntax error. Then I found out that SQLite doesn't support `DELETE JOINS`. How to use `ON DELETE CASCADE` for the above table structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the following code will do as you want/have described :-

```
DROP TABLE tableg;
DROP TABLE tableb;
DROP TABLE tablea;
DROP TABLE tablec;
DROP TABLE tabled;
DROP TABLE tablee;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablea (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablec (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabled (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablee (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablef (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableb (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    tbida REFERENCES tablea(id) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
    name,
    tbidc REFERENCES tablec(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    tbidd REFERENCES tabled(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    tbide REFERENCES tablee(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableg (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    name TEXT,
    tbide REFERENCES tablee(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tablea (name) VALUES('A-Fred'),('A-Bert'),('A-Mary'),('A-Sue'),('A-Ann'),('A-Jane'),('A-Tom');
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tablec (name)  VALUES('C-Fred'),('C-Bert'),('C-Mary'),('C-Sue'),('C-Ann'),('C-Jane'),('C-Tom');
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tabled (name)  VALUES('D-Fred'),('D-Bert'),('D-Mary'),('D-Sue'),('D-Ann'),('D-Jane'),('D-Tom');
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tablee (name)  VALUES('E-Fred'),('E-Bert'),('E-Mary'),('E-Sue'),('E-Ann'),('E-Jane'),('E-Tom');

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tableb (name, tbida, tbidc, tbidd, tbide) VALUES
    ('B-X1',1,1,1,1),
    ('B-Y1',1,3,4,5),
    ('B-Z1',6,2,2,2)
;
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tableg (name, tbide) VALUES('G-X1',5),('G-Y1',3),('G-Z1',4);

SELECT * FROM tablea 
    JOIN tableb ON tablea.id = tbida
    JOIN tablec ON tablec.id = tbidc
    JOIN tabled ON tabled.id - tbidd
    JOIN tablee ON tablee.id = tableb.tbide
    JOIN tableg ON tableg.id = tablee.id
;

DELETE FROM tablea WHERE id = 1; -- <<<<<<<<<<

SELECT * FROM tablea 
    JOIN tableb ON tablea.id = tbida
    JOIN tablec ON tablec.id = tbidc
    JOIN tabled ON tabled.id - tbidd
    JOIN tablee ON tablee.id = tableb.tbide
    JOIN tableg ON tableg.id = tablee.id
;
```

The first result is (i.e loaded related data (as per fully joining tables)) :-

[image]

The second result after deletion of the first row from table**A** (i.e. **A-Fred**) :-

[image]

**That is ON DELETE CASCADE performs the hierarchical deletions when `DELETE FROM tablea WHERE id = 1;` is actioned**